# Phone Remote Access to Exchange

Tags: exchange-2010

What are the different ways a user could potentially accessing emails using a cell phone and exchange?  I would like to know how to prevent someone from accessing emails remotely through any means.  In Exchange 2010 Management Console under Recipient Configuration -> Mailbox -> Right Click User -> Properties -> Mailbox Features Tab -> The following are disabled:

- Outlook Web App
- Exchange ActiveSync
- Unified Messaging
- POP3
- IMAP4

MAPI is still enabled for outlook access internally.  Outlook WebApp and Exchange ActiveSync are enabled for a few select people only.  Are there any other ways to restrict access where someone may be using another method to connect to their emails?

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty much it. 
I am not aware of any MAPI clients for mobile phones. 
Are you publishing Outlook Anywhere externally? That is the only one you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  Found out this was enabled, will look into ways to restrict access to Outlook Anywhere.

Comment: That isn't very straight forward though. Without additional tools/products it is an all off or all on option. 
Furthermore when you upgrade to Exchange 2013 or higher, it is the connection method, so you cannot just turn it off. You will need to look at controlling the publishing of Outlook Anywhere.